# Unable to authorize Opensearch Terraform provider without internal database master user

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, opensearch

I'm trying to create an index management policy in Opensearch 1.3 on AWS using Terraform and the elasticsearch provider from phillbaker but I'm always getting a 403 forbidden exception when using an IAM master user. After several tries, I've changed to an internal database user  and it worked straightaway once the domain access policy was open for any user.

These are the things I've tried so far:

1. Creating an IAM user with programmatic credentials, adding this user to the domain access policy and as a master user for the cluster and using the credentials in the provider (using aws_access_key and aws_secret_access_key parameters, not username and password).
2. Creating an IAM role with administrator access, adding this role as a master user. Configuring a Cognito user pool and identity pool as identity provider for the cluster and configuring authenticated users to use the role created before. Configuring the domain access policy to allow anyone to user the cluster.
3. Creating an internal user from the dashboard and adding this user to the all_access role. Configuring the domain access policy to allow anyone to use the cluster.

In all these cases, it didn't work. The last case, I tried after changing the configuration to use an internal database user as master and I verified both had the same rol mapping configuration. But only the credentials of the one I assigned through the AWS console worked.

I also tried changing the cluster security configuration on AWS so the domain access policy gets replaced with the fine-grained access control. But every time I save the changes, when I get back to the security tab, the domain access policy is still activated.